# Auto Generate Id with Composite Id in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to add auto generate id to my entity class

Here is my entity class

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Audited
    @IdClass(TranKey.class)
    
 public class Tran{
    
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;
    
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private TranSourceEnum tranSource;
    
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @Column(unique = true)
        private String tranId;
    
        private String responseCode;
    
        private String failureReason;
    
        @NotNull
        private Date tranCreSysDate;
    
        private String switchingId;

    }
```

Here is composite key class

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Embeddable
    public class TransKey implements Serializable {
    
        @Column(name = "tranSource")
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        TranSourceEnum tranSource;
    
        @Column(name = "tranId")
        String tranId;
    
        public TransKey(){}
    
        public TransactionKey(TranSourceEnum tranSource, String tranId){
            super();
            this.tranId = tranId;
            this.tranSource = tranSource;
        }
    }
```

I want to add auto generate id field as above entity class...But it is not work....
Not auto generate....it is possible add another id field with composite key..

if it is possible what is the right way

Thank You

Comment: The concept of a @Idclass is to use it as composite key for the class. You need to mention id inside your class TransKey(). You can define generate strategy inside the TransKey class

Comment: It has problem..if tranId=10 tranSource= ATM; then ok....again transId=10 transSourse=ATM show Invalid Input.....So if i mention id in TransKey then will not show Invalid input..it will save @mattyman

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   @IdClass(TranKey.class)
public class Tran{
    
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TranSourceEnum tranSource;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String tranId;

    private String responseCode;

    private String failureReason;

    @NotNull
    private Date tranCreSysDate;

    private String switchingId;

}
```

Write key class like this:

```
@Getter @Setter

public class TransKey implements Serializable {
    
    private TranSourceEnum tranSource;
    private String tranId;
    private Integer id;
    }
```

Comment: It has problem..if tranId=10 tranSource= ATM; then ok....again transId=10 transSourse=ATM show Invalid Input.....So if i mention id in TransKey then will not show Invalid input..it will save. Because this moment id different @mattyman –

Comment: the concept is that for one composite key only one record. So for tranId=10 tranSource= ATM; you want multiple records, you can use the id field. for eg. tranId=10 tranSource= ATM;id=1000000 for one record... tranId=10 tranSource= ATM;id=1000001 for next record.. so on

Comment: tranId=10 tranSource= ATM;id=1000000, tranId=10 tranSource= ATM;id=1000001....this two record must not be in table same time. because tranId and transSourc same..